# how to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Most of the code for the ActionCable setup in my Rails app is in a file that only seems to load when I am visiting the page that is named after the resource. In this case, `scroll_bottom()` runs when I am on the messages `#index`, but throws an error in console when I am anywhere else.

I can tell that this has something to do with `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->`. How can I exclude `scroll_bottom()` when I am not on the `#index` page?

**messages.coffee**

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create "MessagesChannel",
 connected: ->
  console.log 'Connected'

 disconnected: ->
  console.log 'Disconnected'

 received: (data) ->
  alert data["mmmm"]

 peak: (message, conversation_id) ->
  @perform 'speak', message: message, conversation_id: conversation_id

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
 submit_message()
 scroll_bottom()

submit_message = () ->
 $('#response').on 'keydown', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13
   message = event.target.value
   conversation_id = $("#messages").data("conversation-id")
   App.messages.speak(message, conversation_id)
   event.target.value = ""
   event.preventDefault()

scroll_bottom = () ->
 $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scroll_bottom = () ->
 $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight)
```

Change this function to:

```
scroll_bottom = () => {
 const el = $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0]
 if (el) {
  return el.scrollHeight;
 }
}
```

That way if el is not defined no error will be thrown

Comment: this code throws a syntax error. doesn't that `scrollTop($('#messages')[0]` need a closing parenthesis? edit: adding a parenthesis does not fix the syntax error

Comment: Yes, change it to `=>` from `->`

Comment: what causes the syntax error is the constant. also i think `scrollTop` is still missing the closing parenthesis. what does work is `scroll_bottom = () ->
    if $('#messages').length > 0
      $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight)`